# how do i display all records of a field using php in a mysql database

Tags: php

So i want to get all records of a specific field in a table using mysql database

so far i tried this but it only echos the first ever record in that field

```
$query = ("SELECT txtpath,txtname FROM txtdocs WHERE subject='$ref'");
$result = mysql_query($query);  
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//iterate over all the rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //iterate over all the fields
    foreach($row as $key => $val){
        //generate output
        echo $key . ": " . $val . "<BR />";
    }
}
```

Also yes i have more than 1 record in my database

Edit: I added 1 more row so i can have a total of 3 rows, but it's only showing me 2 out of 3 records now.

Comment: I suggest you also add the query itself to your question. Thanks!

Comment: And BTW: is there a reason why you don't do _any_ error checking and handling _at all_ ?

Comment: @arkascha Sorry i forgot to place it in, also there are no errors, it does display one record but that's it really, i'm new to Php and i'm learning, i just want to display all records of a specific field in my table, but it's only displaying 1 record

Comment: Please dump `$count`, what does it show? 1 or something else?

Comment: Another side node: you are using the deprecated (old and outdated) `mysql_...()` functions. You want to switch _now_ to the alternate `mysqli` extension. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Ah.... The code looks fine to me, but might it be that one of the entries in the database contains characters interpreted as html markup? Please add some `html entities()` inside the `echo` statement. Or, as an easy test, use `print_r()` inside the `<pre></pre>` block temporary.

Comment: Can you pin down a pattern _which_ row is missing? Always the same or always the first or last?

Comment: @arkascha First or last.

Comment: What do you mean "or"? It should at least be predictable.

Comment: And once more: please dump the array you get back once as mentioned above.

Comment: @arkascha No i was just referring to your statement, it's the last.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to use loop inside the loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row["txtname"] . ": " . $row["txtpath"]. "<br/>"; 
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If value if `$ref` is ENGLISH than your query must return three records not two. Now you need to debug further NY checking the column value maybe you have some space around column value like `" ENGLISH"`.

**UPDATE 2:**

Further more execute your `SELECT` query in phpmyadmin and check how many rows return.

```
SELECT txtpath,txtname FROM txtdocs WHERE subject="English";
```

**Side note**:

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` its deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It might be seen as a form of optimization, though questionable, since you don't know the OPs motivation for the current implementation. But certainly it does not answer the issue at hand.

Comment: @arkascha if its really not a answer I will remove it.

Comment: @arkascha That works, but again it only displays all but one of the records for some reason.

Comment: @BaheegAhmed I never claimed this "does not work". I said: it does not address the issue at hand, which is exactly what you confirmed now.

Comment: @baheeg-ahmed if u have three records against SELECT txtpath,txtname FROM txtdocs WHERE subject='$ref' query it will display three

Comment: @devpro http://prntscr.com/9zoh95 is what it shows, in database:- http://prntscr.com/9zoj6g

Comment: @baheeg-ahmed u have two records in database

Comment: @baheeg-ahmed plz share what u figured because some one down vote the answer.

Comment: @arkascha my friend reason of down voting is not an answer just?

Comment: @arkascha. Yes three I assume first one is column name :p

Comment: It is a combination of the fact that this "answer" does indeed not answer the question and the fact that you appear not to understand that. Sorry, it takes a while until I down vote something. But this is just too much. There is no sense in such "I also know something!" answers just to post something. Can you say _why_ there is only 2 of 3 rows shown? No? Then this is NOT an answer.

Comment: And about your last comment: "first one is column name": start using your brain! That is _not_ column headers. First: you see the `edit` marks on the left? In a header row? Never. And second: note the entry "Yeah" is shown twice. Two columns cannot have the same name. Third: the last column should be the one called `subject` or how else should the query work? Those are _three_ valid entries.

Comment: @arkascha agreed all points.. If value of $ref is equal to ENGLISH it must return three records but it returns two and count is also said its two

Comment: No, `$count` holding the value `2` was a statement done _before_ the OP added the third entry.

Comment: @arkascha I think for third row it have some space along with ENGLISH in column... Plz correct me if I m wrong..

Comment: @devpro This might be the case, indeed.

Comment: @devpro Actually no, this does not match with what the OP said about the content of `$count`. But anyway, since your "answer" is accepted and the OP keeps silent we should assume that not everything the OP wrote is necessarily true. So everything else would be guess work.

Comment: Yes my friend I accepted your all comments. We must need the last comment from OP . I Also comment for OP please share what y figured and OP removed his comments @arkascha

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work!

```
//$dbname= 'your connection to database';
$result = mysqli_query($dbname, 'SELECT txtpath,txtname FROM txtdocs WHERE subject="'.$ref.'"');
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//iterate over all the rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['txtpath'] . ': ' .$row['txtname']. '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Is it fools day today? This is a variant of @devpro's question below. _It does not address the issue at all_. This is _not_ an answer. _Why_ should it deliver another result?

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that you can't explain and can't listen. I guess:

You have 3 records in table now, yes?

Before You had 2 records and displays only one.

Next you added new record and displays 2 of 3.

In your SQL query you have WHERE statement => I guess that record which not displayed does not satisfy the condition.

The easiest way to check this is dump/echo **$count**.

Can you display this? If result is 2 I am right, if not we can think further.

UNFORTUNATELLY people don't think yourself, just ask and lose your time and other.

Comment: This is impressive. You claim others don't listen and don't think and waste others time. Yet this "answer" (which is _not_ an answer) clearly shows that it is _you_ who has not read or understood the information given here.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to display all record of a specific field in a table, you have to remove "where" condition because if condition contain only one column in table then it will be display only one record.

```sql
$query = ("SELECT txtpath,txtname FROM txtdocs");
$result = mysql_query($query);  
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//iterate over all the rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //iterate over all the fields
    foreach($row as $key => $val){
        //generate output
        echo $key . ": " . $val . "<BR />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. 1. several rows may hold the same value in the `subject` column and 2. the `$count` variable shows a value of 2 or 3, as stated by the OP.

Comment: @Ankesh Vaishnav No sir, i wanna display all fields in a table with a specific condition.

Comment: Please try using mysql_fetch_array()